# Those fields where all elements can be generated from 1 by addition, subtraction and multiplication.

Tags: field-theory

Consider a field $(F,+,-,*,0,1)$. Let $S$ be the smallest subset of $F$ that is closed under $1$,$+$,$-$, and $*$. Assuming that $S=F$, must $F$ be a finite field? In fact, must $F$ be finite of prime number cardinality?

Comment: $S$ is the image of the unit map $\mathbb{Z} \to F$. This map is surjective iff $F$ is a quotient of $\mathbb{Z}$, and if $F$ is a field that quotient can only be $\mathbb{Z}/p$ for some prime $p$.

Comment: In somewhat less high-powered language, what happens if you keep adding $1$? If you never get zero, then the closure under the specified operations is the integers, not a field. If you do get zero, then arguing from the nonexistence of zero divisors it must be after you've added a prime number of $1$s, so you're in a field with a prime number of elements.

Comment: Any thoughts on the comments, 107952?

Comment: It's not polite, 107952, to ask a question and then ignore the people who try to help you answer it.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Sorry. That does answer the question. Maybe you can post it as an answer. I am sorry if my question was amateur-ish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Comment promoted to answer, at suggestion of OP]

Consider the sequence $$1,1+1,1+1+1, 1+1+1+1,\dots$$ If zero never shows up in this sequence, then the closure (under addition, subtraction, and multiplication) is the integers, not a field. If zero does show up, let $n$ be the smallest number of $1$s adding up to zero. Then $n$ must be prime (since, if $n=rs$, the distributive law shows that zero is the product of the sum of $r$ ones and the sum of $s$ ones, and the nonexistence of zero divisors in a field implies $\{\,r,s\,\}=\{\,1,n\,\}$), hence the closure is a field with a prime number of elements.